Spool to pdf with CPYSPLF fails - CPFCE06 with reason code 8 - The transform interface detected a logic error
On one of iSeries machines (V7R5M0) I am creating PDF from spool file, like:
CPYSPLF FILE(QPJOBLOG) TOFILE(*TOSTMF) SPLNBR(*LAST) CRTDATE(*LAST) TOSTMF("/home/TE000667/test.pdf") WSCST(*PDF) STMFOPT(*REPLACE) JOB(569877/TE000667/QPADEV000C)

This works on multiple machines, but on one specific it ends with error:
Message ID . . . . . . :   CPFCE06       Severity . . . . . . . :   40      
Message type . . . . . :   Diagnostic                                       
Date sent  . . . . . . :   12.04.24      Time sent  . . . . . . :   10:09:31
                                                                            
Message . . . . :   Error occurred while transforming print data.           
Cause . . . . . :   A critical error occurred with the transform service job
  used to transform the print data. The reason code is 8.  The reason codes 
  and their meaning are:                                                    
    1 -- The communication connection was lost. The server job may have     
  terminated unexpectedly.                                                  
    2 -- A storage allocation request failed.                               
    3 -- A request to open a temporary file failed.                         
    4 -- A request to open a product file failed.                           
    5 -- A font configuration file had invalid syntax.                      
    6 -- A required parameter was invalid.                                  
    7 -- The transform interface detected a syntax error.                   
Message ID . . . . . . :   CPFCE06       Severity . . . . . . . :   40        
Message type . . . . . :   Diagnostic                                         
                                                                              
    8 -- The transform interface detected a logic error.                      
    9 -- The transform detected corruption of heap storage.                   
    10 -- An invalid communication protocol message was received.             
    11 -- The transform interface detected a handler error.                   
Recovery  . . . :   Check any previous messages in the joblog. Correct any    
  errors and try the request again.  If the problem persists, report the      
  problem (ANZPRB command).                                                   
Technical description . . . . . . . . :   The internal error had a severity of
  2, a major code of 64, and a minor code of 5456.  The internal message      
  identifier is FUY04579.

Message details:
Message ID . . . . . . :   CPFCE06       Severity . . . . . . . :   40        
Date sent  . . . . . . :   18.04.24      Time sent  . . . . . . :   14:16:19  
Message type . . . . . :   Diagnostic                                         
From . . . . . . . . . :   TE000667      CCSID  . . . . . . . . :   65535     
                                                                              
From program . . . . . . . . . :   QCTXFORM                                   
  From library . . . . . . . . :     QSYS                                     
  From module  . . . . . . . . :     CTXEVENT                                 
  From procedure . . . . . . . :     API_Event_Mapper__FP10qctxform_tP9ctt_eve
      nt                                                                      
  From statement . . . . . . . :     436                                      
                                                                              
To program . . . . . . . . . . :   QSPWRKF                                    
  To library . . . . . . . . . :     QSYS                                     
  Instruction  . . . . . . . . :     01F8                                     

DSPSYSVAL QCCSID is 65535 also job CCSID is 65535. Spool file has
Character identifier:                           
  Graphic character set  . . . . . . . :   *DEVD
  Code page  . . . . . . . . . . . . . :        

Error happens for every spool file and only on this machine (other machines with  V7R5M0 do generate PDF). Exporting to txt instead (without WSCST(*PDF) ) works. I expected we miss some module related to PDF printing but system administrators found no issue with what is installed compared to other machines. Searching google did not help, there are some hits, but for other reason codes, and for this reason there is only one page here but without any hints of a solution. I also compared WSCST  via RTVWSCST and it is same on all machines (but it is not human readable like in this tutorial )
Does anyone know a solution?
Answering additional questions:

Do I have a write rights? Yes, I am using same command without WSCST(*PDF) to store text to same directory just fine.
Are there PTF differences bethween machines? Yes, but only minor and looking irrelevant. Only difference is for SI50932, SI55064, SI57424 and the difference is only that on failing machine it is "Temporarily applied" instead of "Permanently applied"
Does it run with QSECOFR (or *ALLOBJ)? I tested with both with no change
Is it a mirrored(guest) system? No, mirroring is not running there.
CHKPRDOPT PRDID(5770TS1) OPTION(*BASE) and CHKPRDOPT PRDID(5770TS1) OPTION(1) return "No errors detected by CHKPRDOPT"


I’m voting to close this question because it would seem to be more appropriate for ServerFault .  If there's not enough of a midrange community there, then try the Midrange Mailing List

Midrange community here! :-)
ServerFault tag AS400 is zero, and midrange virtually dead.

@Piro, have you seen this one:
https://www.ibm.com/mysupport/s/defect/aCI0z0000004TzR/dt045797?language=en_US
https://www.ibm.com/mysupport/s/fix-information/aDr3p000000gFXiCAM/fi0057123?language=en_US

@Piro Hmmm .... Difficult to catch ... what are the From/To Program names of the msg? What is DSPSYSVAL QCCSID, Spool File CCSID, Job CCSID? Has the error occured all the time on the system / before/after Installation of V7R5? Has there ever been a RST operation on the IFS?

@Piro Is this a mirrored (guest-)system? Also, there could be the user exits QIBM_QPQ_TRANSFORM and
QIBM_QIMG_TRANSFORMS involved. Here is a good article from IBM about this topic that could help to narrow down the issue: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/using-transform-services-generate-pdf-stream-files-instead-spooled-files
I have also prepared a test program that calls Transform Services API directly without writing to the IFS, which could help to determine at which stage the error happens. (How can I send this to you - possibly via PUB400 ?)

@WStanzl I added more info (More info later). If you have any source code, feel free to use what is convenient for you. I think that could be even answer here. Not sure if possible but I will try to debug QCTXFORM

@Piro for the test program, I'd prefer at this stage we do this via PUB400 so we can modify it quickly; you can always save/restore the object to your system.

@WStanzl Sure I can work with PUB400, but I do need source code. Security rules

@Piro Send me a msg to pub400 user WRSTANZL, so I know which user you are on PUB400. If we could find a way to speak to each other that might make things easier?

@WStanzl lets continue in chat
